# Drupal Custom Module returning wrong title

Tags: drupal, menu, title

For my drupal website, in my custom module (hr_payroll.module) I have the following to add URL handlers:

```
function hr_payroll_menu() {
  $items['hr/payroll/employee/hours/overtime'] = array(
    'title' => 'Overtime Submission',
    'page callback' => 'hr_payroll_page',
    'page arguments' => array('employee','hours','overtime'),
    'access arguments' => array('access hr payroll'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['hr/payroll'] = array(
    'title' => 'Payroll',
    'page callback' => 'hr_payroll_intro',
    'access arguments' => array('access hr payroll'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

On my site is a block that simply contains
    `echo(drupal_get_title());`

If I go the URL `hr/payroll`, it shows the title 'Payroll'
BUT if I go to the URL `hr/payroll/employee/hours/overtime` it still shows 'Payroll' instead of the expected 'Overtime Submission'

So what am I totally misunderstanding about how the $title element of the menu item or the `function drupal_get_title()` work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the hook_menu in the wrong way based on what you want to do.
First menu

```
$items['hr/payroll/employee/hours/overtime'] = array(
    'title' => 'Overtime Submission',
    'page callback' => 'hr_payroll_page',
    'page arguments' => array('employee','hours','overtime'),
    'access arguments' => array('access hr payroll'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

Are the arguments 'employee' 'hours' 'overtime' are static or they are dynamic ?? , and I see that page arguments supplied are the same ('employee','hours','overtime')
If they are dynamic use wildcard instead like

```
 $items['hr/payroll/%/%/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Overtime Submission',
        'page callback' => 'hr_payroll_page',
        'page arguments' => array(2,3,4),
        'access arguments' => array('access hr payroll'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
```

If the menu link "hr/payroll/employee/hours/overtime" is static , that means you don't need the access arguments provided as u already know what these values are on your page callback function.

And also why are you using type as MENU_CALLBACK.Is that by reason or by just random??